# Spark : How to get the latest file from s3 in the last 10 days

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the latest file from s3 in last 10 days when there is no file exist in the input. The issue is the path contains the date.

My path is like this :

```
val path = "s3://bucket-info/folder1/folder2"

val date = "2019/04/12"    ## YYYY/MM/DD
```

I am doing this =

```
 val update_path = path+"/" +date //this will become s3://bucket-info/folder1/folder2/2019/04/12 


def fileExist(path: String, sc: SparkContext): Boolean = FileSystem.get(getS3OrFileUri(path),
  sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path(path + "/_SUCCESS"))


if (fileExist(update_path, sc)) {
    //read and process the file

} else {
       log("File not exist")
       // I need to get the latest file in the last five days and use. So that I can check "s3://bucket-info/folder1/folder2/2019/04/11" , s3://bucket-info/folder1/folder2/2019/04/10 and others. If no latest file in last 5 days. throw error. s

}
```

But my issue is how do I check when it is the end of the month ? I can do it in for loop but is there any optimized and elegant way to do this in spark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very optimal but if you want to utilise Spark, the data frame reader can take multiple paths and `input_file_name` gives you the path:

```
val path = "s3://bucket-info/folder1/folder2"
val date = "2019/04/12"
val fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd")
val end = LocalDate.parse(date, fmt)
val prefixes = (0 until 10).map(end.minusDays(_)).map(d => s"$path/${fmt.format(d)}")

val prefix = spark.read
  .textFile(prefixes:_*)
  .select(input_file_name() as "file")
  .distinct()
  .orderBy(desc("file"))
  .limit(1)
  .collect().collectFirst {
  case Row(prefix: String) => prefix
}

prefix.fold {
  // log error
}
{ path =>
  //read and process the file
}
```

This is quite inefficient and there is no clear way around that using Spark as the S3 Hadoop file system implementation is not very efficient using recursive structures. If you are willing to use S3 API directly, you could set `s"$path/${fmt.format(end.minusDays(10))}"` as a [start after](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Request.html#setStartAfter-java.lang.String-) parameter and use something [like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html) to list the keys. This works as S3 always returns the key listings sorted alphabetically and you have zero padding in date keys.